# Get data from Observable in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular7

I am fairly new to  Angular. Trying to consume  data as follows from a GET REST Endpoint-

```
{"employees":[{"empId":"1","name":"emp1","designation":"manager","salary":3000.0},{"empId":"2","name":"emp2","designation":"developer","salary":3000.0}],"addresses":[{"city":"London"},{"city":"Belgium"}]}
```

It has two lists employees and addresses.
In angular i have created the classes as follows-

```
export class Employee {

  constructor(

  ) { }
}

export class Address {

  constructor(

  ) { }
}



export class EmployeeDetail {
  public employees: Employee[];
  public addresses: Address[];

  constructor( ) { }
  public get employee(): Employee[] {
    return this.employees;
  }

  public get address(): Address[] {
    return this.addresses;
  }

  public set address(addresses: Address[]){
    this.addresses = addresses;
}

}
```

Trying to construct the EmployeeDetail class as follows-

```
getData() {
    return this.httpClient.get<EmployeeDetail>('http://localhost:8080/employees')
    .pipe(
      map(data => {
        const employeeList: Employee[] = [];
        const addressList: Address[] = [];
        var employeeDetail = new EmployeeDetail();
        const newList1 : Employee[] = data.employee;
        const newList2 : Address[] = data.address;
        console.log(newList1);
        newList1.forEach(item => 
          employeeList.push(Object.assign(new Employee(), item)));
        newList2.forEach(item => 
          newList.push(Object.assign(new Address(), item)));  
          employeeDetail.employee = employeeList;
          employeeDetail.address = addressList;


        return employeeDetail;
      })
   );
```

Getting following exception

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at MapSubscriber.project (http-client.service.ts:119)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:41)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:38)
    at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
```

Could some one please help me create the EmployeeDetail object. Thanks

Comment: It's `data.employees` not `data.employee`.

Comment: and data.addresses not data.address

Comment: Please use a debugger before you post questions. Adding a simple `debugger;` and taking a look at what is happening will help you a lot in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys :)..it solved the problem. Just a question. even using data.employee  should call the getter right? Which will return the data.employees

Comment: @Reactgular no need for a `debugger`, just a `console.log` is enough

Comment: @Maryannah true, but if we could get more people to use `debugger;` the quality of questions here would go up. ;)

Comment: @Reactgular can't agree more ! [But template debugging is coming](https://blog.angularindepth.com/embrace-yourself-angular-8-is-coming-1bf187c8f0bf) so we got that going, which is nice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to put in all that redundant logic in the `getData()` method.

How about simplifying your implementation like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class Employee {
  empId: string;
  name: string;
  designation: string;
  salary: number;
}

export class Address {
  city: string;
}

export class EmployeeDetail {
  employees: Employee[];
  addresses: Address[];
}

@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getEmployeeData(): Observable < EmployeeDetail > {
    return this.http.get < EmployeeDetail > ('/assets/employees.json');
  }

}
```

---

We just specify the `T` of the `get` method on the `HttpClient` to `EmployeeDetail` and return whatever this method returns. This would return an `Observable` wrapping a value of type `EmployeeDetail`.

---

> Here's a **[Working Sample StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/simplifying-data-fetch-and-assignment-in-angular?file=src/app/employee.service.ts)** for your ref.